# Can't set parameter with type of base class by value of derived class

Tags: blazor

Component:

```
...
[Parameter]
public Base InitialModel {get;set;}
...
```

Model:

```
record Base() {}
record Derived():Base {}
```

Usage:

```
<component type="typeof(...)" param-InitialModel="@(new Derived())" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />

.....
```

Result:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter 'InitialModel with type 'Base' in assembly '...' could not be found.
```

Expected:

Derived classes accepted in place of base class

Comment: [Polite] A bit terse.  I'm failing to see what you're trying to achieve.  Where are you defining `<component type="typeof(...)" param-InitialModel="@(new Derived())" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />`

Comment: Did you find a solution or more info on this issue? I am facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I just solved it.

I had to register the class with the services DI system. In the WASM project edit the program.cs file to add the class to the services

```
      public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            //builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
            builder.Services.AddScoped<MyViewModel, MyViewModel>();   // <= add this line

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

related question: [How to pass ViewModels into Razor Components in .NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308011/how-to-pass-viewmodels-into-razor-components-in-net-core-3-1/69111436#69111436)